# How can I use the select function of DefaultSqlSession?

Tags: java

I have a question while using the mybatis's sqlSession 'select' function. I know that sqlSession is an interface. And I know that  mybatis's DefaultSqlSession.java implements this. So I looked at the DefaultSqlSession.java code

```
@Override
   public void select(String statement, ResultHandler handler) {
     select(statement, null, RowBounds.DEFAULT, handler);
   }
```

The method above is the 'select' method of DefaultSqlSession.java.

What I'm curious about is select(statement, null, RowBounds.DEFAULT, handler);
That function is not defined in DefaultSqlSession.java, so I wonder how it can be used.

I wonder where the  mybatis's sqlsession select statement was fundamentally implemented.

Comment: [DefaultSqlSession](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/621de2602b7d6bc1ba65237b26409ebeb086c45a/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/session/defaults/DefaultSqlSession.java#L173) does have the implementation, delegating to `selectList` which contains the actual logic.

Comment: There was something I missed, thank you!